# Unable to Catch Specific Exception

Tags: c#

I am serializing a XML File.During the serialization ,I am receiving general exception.It is hard trace the problem.

my code is:

---

try

{

 string m_fileName = @"d:\Xml\Person.xml";

XmlSerializer xmlPerSerlzr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(person));

txtWrt = new StreamWriter(m_fileName);

xmlPerSerlzr.Serialize(txtWrt, person);

}

catch(Exception serExp)

     {

        MessageBox.Show("Exception is :" + serExp.Message.ToString());

     }

---

Error Message :

There was an error reflecting type "Person"

---

My question is how can i force the CLR to emit the exact error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to check also the stack trace and the inner exception.

You can use something like that

```
    string GetExceptionString(Exception ex)
    {
        string str = "";
        while (ex != null)
        {
            str += ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace;
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the type of the exception, e.g.

```
serExp.GetType().ToString()
```

and check for an inner exception (both type and message).

That should give you some more useful info.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
exc.ToString();
```

In Debug mode in Exception DialogBox, select **View details** option.
Probably You don't implement 0-parameter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
serExp.StackTrace
```

instead of

```
serExp.Message.ToString()
```

Comment: Better, serExp.ToString(), which does both of the above in one -- one of the cases where .ToString() is not a completely useless statement of the object type.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in the catch clause, then run in debug mode. You can then explore the exception object easier and figure out what is going on.